# Change the values of a column in a DataGridView C#

Tags: c#, datagridview

I'm populating a datagridview with Entity from my database, there's a column with a foreing key (its an ID column from other table). I'd like to know how to change that column, I mean, instead of showing that ID column, I want to show the names from those ID's.

Example:

```
 I|C|S
--------
 1|1|A

I = ID for each row in that table.
C = Client ID.
S = State (A = Active).
```

Supposing that's my datagridview, I'd like to change that Cliente ID for his/her name.

Comment: Why don't you just put the name of the client with that id instead of the id itself when populating the datagridview? What's the problem? How are you doing it?

Comment: I populate the datagridview with entity. And I dont know if there's a way to do it with entity.

Comment: A code example would be greatly appreciated. If you are not able to do it while populating whatsoever, you can always just retype all the cells in that column and put the client with that ID after you've gotten it from the cell.

Comment: private datacontext dc = new datacontext();
        private void Form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DataGridView.DataSource = dc.DataSet.ToList();

        }

Comment: thats how I populate my datagridview

Comment: How do you actually find a client by his ID, where are clients stored and etc.?

Comment: Clients are stored in other table. I have other form where I load all my client on a combobox (I show their names, and I have a code that when I press the button Add, it seek that name in the database and select the ID, and it add's it to the datagridview).

Comment: So why don't you just add directly the name instead of seaking the ID. I can't understand... Can you still give an example of finding a client by his ID separately from those functions?

Comment: because when I add to the datagridview, at the same time I'm adding it to the database, then I can't add the name from a client (a string) to the ID column (an int).

Comment: You might want to separate the function that adds the client to the database and the one that populates the gridview. The other option is, as I said, to rewrite the data in the column of the datagridview afterwards, but for that I'd need to actually have the way to find a name of a client by his ID. Could you show how it's done for you?